# S3 Bucket Policy and Lambda Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket named `x-temp-images` and a corresponding bucket policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::x-temp-images-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": <LAMBDA_ARN>
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

I have two Lambda functions:

- one with the desired ARN to access `x-temp-images` and
- another Lambda function that I don't want to access the `x-temp-images` bucket.

I have given both Lambda functions full S3 access for testing purposes, while I don't want to specify in each Lambda function role whether they have access to specific S3 buckets or not. Despite this, both Lambda functions can access this bucket, even though I have mentioned only the ARN of the first Lambda function in the S3 bucket policy.

Comment: Your bucket policy deny statement has no effect because it is not the AWS Lambda service principal that is accessing the bucket; it's the IAM role that the Lambda function was launched with instead.

Answer (score 1):

The Condition you have specified in the policy will not work.

If you want to grant an AWS Lambda function permission to access an Amazon S3 bucket, you should **grant permission in the IAM Role associated with the Lambda function**.

By default, an IAM Role has no permissions. Therefore, no action is required for the IAM Role on the Lambda function that you do *not* want to access the S3 bucket.

For the Lambda function that you want to have access to the S3 bucket, **add permission to its IAM Role**.